# __construct() must implement interface error

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I use symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle, SonataMediaBundle and SonataClassificationBundle

Now I want custmize setting for admin panel, but I have this error.

```
 [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                 
  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 5 passed to Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMe  
  diaAdmin::__construct() must implement interface Sonata\ClassificationBundl  
  e\Model\CategoryManagerInterface, none given, called in /Users/whitebear/Codin  
  gWorks/httproot/myapp/app/cache/de_/appDevDebugProjectContaine_.php on l  
  ine 9494 and defined in . (which is being imported from "/Users/whitebear/Codi  
  ngWorks/httproot/myapp/app/config/routing.yml").
```

What I have done is two things.

made DependencyInjection file

Application/Sonata/MediaBundle/DependencyInjection/ApplicationSonataMediaExtension.php

```
  <?php

namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class ApplicationSonataMediaExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

then made services.yml for admin

Application/Sonata/MediaBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
#Disable gallery & media menu from admin panel
services:
    sonata.media.admin.media:
        class: %sonata.media.admin.media.class%
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, show_in_dashboard: false, label_catalogue: %sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain% , label_translator_strategy: sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - %sonata.media.admin.media.entity%
            - %sonata.media.admin.media.controller%
            - "@sonata.media.pool"
            - %sonata.classification.manager.category% # add here.

        calls:
            - [setModelManager, ["@sonata.media.admin.media.manager"]]
            - [setTranslationDomain, [%sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain%]]
            - [setTemplates, [{ inner_list_row: SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:inner_row_media.html.twig , base_list_field: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_flat_field.html.twig , list: SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list.html.twig , edit: SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:edit.html.twig }]]

    sonata.media.admin.gallery:
        class: %sonata.media.admin.gallery.class%
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, show_in_dashboard: false, label_catalogue: %sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain% , label_translator_strategy: sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - %sonata.media.admin.gallery.entity%
            - %sonata.media.admin.gallery.controller%
            - "@sonata.media.pool"
        calls:
            - [setTranslationDomain, [%sonata.media.admin.media.translation_domain%]]
            - [setTemplates, [{ list: SonataMediaBundle:GalleryAdmin:list.html.twig }]]
```

in Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin

```
abstract class BaseMediaAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    /**
     * @var Pool
     */
    protected $pool;

    /**
     * @var CategoryManagerInterface
     */
    protected $categoryManager;

    /**
     * @param string                   $code
     * @param string                   $class
     * @param string                   $baseControllerName
     * @param Pool                     $pool
     * @param CategoryManagerInterface $categoryManager
     */
    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, Pool $pool, CategoryManagerInterface $categoryManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);

        $this->pool = $pool;

        $this->categoryManager = $categoryManager;
    }
```

---

Thanks to  @mdma
I figured out I must path 5th parameters as CategoryManagerInterface to BaseMediaAdmin constructor.

then I updated the service.yml but I have error like this.

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
  The service "sonata.media.admin.media" has a dependency on a non-existent p   
  arameter "sonata.classification.manager.category". Did you mean one of thes   
  e: "sonata.classification.manager.category.class", "sonata.classification.m   
  anager.tag.class", "sonata.classification.manager.context.class", "sonata.c   
  lassification.manager.tag.entity", "sonata.classification.manager.category.   
  entity", "sonata.classification.manager.context.entity", "sonata.classifica   
  tion.admin.category.class"?
```

---

It solved. 
I changed this sentence inservices.yml

`- %sonata.classification.manager.category%`  to `"@sonata.classification.manager.category"`

Comment: I thing you are missing a contructor parameter in your sonata.media.admin.media, by your error log i thing its something like this: sonata.classification.manager.category

Comment: @mdma Thanks very much. I understood what is missing. I made a progress a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error say : Argument 5 doesn't exist in Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin::__construct()

So, look at arguments in you sonata.media.admin.media service configuration. There are only 4 arguments. You need to add the 5th.

In bundle config (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine_orm_admin.xml), there are 5 arguments :

```
<argument/>
<argument>%sonata.media.admin.media.entity%</argument>
<argument>%sonata.media.admin.media.controller%</argument>
<argument type="service" id="sonata.media.pool"/>
<argument type="service" id="sonata.media.manager.category" on-invalid="null"/>
```

So, I think you can add @sonata.media.manager.category as 5th argument.

Comment: I figure out how it works!! Thank you I have found that same setting is written in doctrine_orm_admin.xml